# Is there any site where I can see the python method signatures?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm amazed to not have come across any such site so far.

For example, when I'm using the Python's dict() function. I want to what are the different parameters that it can accept. Something like the following:

```
return: dict, dict(list)
return: dict, dict(dict)
return: dict, dict(dict + dict)
return: dict, dict(tupple of format = (element=value, element2=value2))
```

Everywhere I search on the Internet it just brings me to limited examples rather than showing me a signature.

Here on Stackoverflow.com, I came across a question that stated we cannot use dict(dict). That dict() function can only be used with a list.

Is there any site/link that shows most of the ways that dict can be used or the signature of dict in the above format?

Comment: I think you are talking about [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html)

Comment: @bro-grammer Negative. I'm at a level where I'm trying to understand what does what. I do have a working knowledge of the concept of dictionaries and I have used it in the past. But I'm trying to gain a high level understanding of dict. Going through 4,500 lines of code would be an overkill IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the official documentation of Python:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/

You will get most of the ideas from it.